# XGBoost algorithm, question about the evaulate_model function

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

This evaulate model function is frequently used, I found it used [here](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/ac820b22cc976f5cf6487260f4c8d9c8) at IBM. But I will show the function here:

```
def evaluate_model(alg, train, target, predictors, useTrainCV=True , cv_folds=5, early_stopping_rounds=50):

    if useTrainCV:
        xgb_param = alg.get_xgb_params()
        xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train[predictors].values, target['Default Flag'].values)
        cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, xgtrain, num_boost_round=alg.get_params()['n_estimators'], nfold=cv_folds,
            metrics='auc', early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds, verbose_eval=True)
        alg.set_params(n_estimators=cvresult.shape[0])

    #Fit the algorithm on the data
    alg.fit(train[predictors], target['Default Flag'], eval_metric='auc')

    #Predict training set:
    dtrain_predictions = alg.predict(train[predictors])
    dtrain_predprob = alg.predict_proba(train[predictors])[:,1]

    #Print model report:
    print("\nModel Report")
    print("Accuracy : %.6g" % metrics.accuracy_score(target['Default Flag'].values, dtrain_predictions))
    print("AUC Score (Train): %f" % metrics.roc_auc_score(target['Default Flag'], dtrain_predprob))  
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
    feat_imp = pd.Series(alg.get_booster().get_fscore()).sort_values(ascending=False)
    feat_imp.plot(kind='bar', title='Feature Importance', color='g')
    plt.ylabel('Feature Importance Score')
    plt.show()
```

After tuning the parameters for XGboost, I have

```
xgb4 = XGBClassifier(
    objective="binary:logistic", 
    learning_rate=0.10,  
    n_esimators=5000,
    max_depth=6,
    min_child_weight=1,
    gamma=0.1,
    subsample=0.8,
    colsample_bytree=0.8,
    reg_alpha=0.1,
    nthread=4,
    scale_pos_weight=1.0,
    seed=27)
features = [x for x in X_train.columns if x not in ['Default Flag','ID']]
evaluate_model(xgb4, X_train, y_train, features)
```

and the results I get is

```
Model Report
Accuracy : 0.803236
AUC Score (Train): 0.856995
```

The question I have and perhaps ill-informed is that this `evaulate_model()` function is not tested on the test set of the data which I found odd. When I do call it on the test set (`evaluate_model(xgb4, X_test, y_test, features)`) I get this

```
Model Report
Accuracy : 0.873706
AUC Score (Train): 0.965286
```

I want to know if these two Model Reports are concerning at all given that the test set has a higher accuracy then the training set. My apologies if the structure of this question is poorly presented.

Comment: This function seems to train on the dataset you give it, and return the train accuracy and AUC : this is therefore not a reliable way to evaluate your models. Your test scores are higher because your test set is smaller, so the model overfit more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will develop my answer a little bit more :

This function train on the dataset you give it, and return the train accuracy and AUC : this is therefore not a reliable way to evaluate your models.

In the link you provided, it is said that this function is used to tune the number of estimators:

> The function below performs the following actions to find the best
>   number of boosting trees to use on your data:
>
> - Trains an XGBoost model using features of the data.
> - Performs k-fold cross validation on the model, using accuracy and AUC    score as the evaluation metric.
> - Returns output for each boosting round so you can see how the model    is learning. You will look at the detailed output in the next
>     section.
> - It stops running after the cross-validation score does not improve    significantly with additional boosting rounds, giving you an
>     optimal number of estimators for the model.

You should not use it to evaluate your model performance, but rather perform a clean cross validation.

Your test scores are higher in this case because your test set is smaller, so the model overfit more easily.